# Is it possible to establish an AWS CodeCommit policy for files?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to control the commit permissions for some users' specific files.

For example, is there a way to apply a policy to prevent someone from committing a * .txt file?

I found a link that seems to be related, but I don't know how to use it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscodecommit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the AWS support team a question and received an answer to that question.

The bottom line is that Git cannot set access to individual files.

The answers to the questions are as follows.

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to only allow or not allow access to a particular file inside a repository. In fact, the only resource supported by AWS CodeCommit API action is repository. You can only control the access of IAM users to a particular repository and not what resides under them if they have access to the repository.
>
> CodeCommit gives you some permission to control your repository/branches/ files etc only if you are using the AWS Console or AWS CLI/API, not Git.